# How to Add JwtBearer along with AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, microsoft-identity-platform

I am not sure I completely understood the changes for Microsoft.Identity.Web but I was following an article ([given by Microsoft here)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-3-AnyOrgOrPersonal) Where it described how to change in startup

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

to

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);
```

while this looks good and easy I have a little more work because I have the following snippet in my existing code

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureAD(options => this.configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
       //this code used to validate signing keys
       string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
       IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
       OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       var tenantId = this.configuration["TenantId"];
       var validIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/";

       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
       {
           ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
           ValidAudience = this.configuration["ClientId"],
           IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys,
       };
  });
```

To give you a little bit of context we have two variations with this application

1. User Login and do some staff (here user will get Microsoft login dialog to login using his/her credential)
2. Microsoft Azure calls our endpoint with some token and we need to validate that token.

The JWTvaliation section you see above is for the 2nd item where once we received a token we validate that token without login and UI workflow.

**Question:**
The above code is working correctly. The only issue here is if we like to use `Microsoft.Identity` how should we use the second item (JWT) because `services.AddAuthentication().AddAzureAD` returns `IAuthenticationBuilder` which we use further to add `AddJwtBearer`, While `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` does not return `IAuthenticationBuilder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` is actually [just a fancy way](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebAppExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebAppServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L35) to do the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(…)
```

So it configures the default scheme to be the OIDC scheme and runs `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` to configure whatever this ends up doing.

Now, [`AddAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-3.1) can actually be called multiple times on the service collection. You just need to be careful not to reconfigure things incorrectly. The parameterless function does not do that, so it is a good way to access the `IAuthenticationBuilder` to further configure authentication.

That means that you can change your code like this:

```
// configure Microsoft Identity Web first
// this also sets the default authentication to OIDC
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

// retrieve an authentication builder without changing the default
services.AddAuthentication()
    // add JWT bearer now
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
       // …
   });
```

Comment: I like your explanation and probably that is the correct answer as well. However, I like to know a very quick alternative whether that's right understanding or that will change the purpose.

Instead of the code you wrote can we have something like 

services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)

In other words, Just add JWTBeaer in the pipeline first and then add MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication - will that also same as your example?

Comment: @BrijeshShah Since `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` has to be called on the service collection, you cannot run it on directly after `AddJwtBearer`. You would have to call it on `services` again. But yes, you could switch those two statements in my example around without affecting anything. The order does only matter for configurations (later configurations may overwrite earlier configurations).